# Parse node.js express app, form enctype="multipart/form-data" destroys request body?

Tags: node.js, parsing, express

i am building an app backend with parse, and i need to do some image uploading, but when i post to the app url with the form enctype being multipart/form-data, the body is empty?

This is the method which recieves the post:

```
// These two lines are required to initialize Express in Cloud Code.
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Global app configuration section
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  // Specify the folder to find templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    // Set the template engine
app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body

app.post('/add_station', function(req, res) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
       res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));

});
```

req.body is empty when the form type is multipart/form-data?

Comment: Which version of expressjs you are using ?

Comment: I can include the markup, its the default behavior, i am using parse, and they include express, im pretty sure its the newest stable version thats used, trying to find it.

The form markup is good, the entire form works fine, when its submitted with a normal enctype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Express 4.0 or higher, it no longer comes bundled with middleware. Meaning you need to require and install them manually.

Body-parser also no longer works with file uploads, so you need to use something like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer')

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(multer({
    dest: './uploads/'
}))
```

Comment: you are missing a semi-colon on line 4

Comment: @w43L luckily the compiler can add that one in.

Comment: I used `Router.use(Multer({dest: './uploads'}))` but get the error `throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware functions');
    ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware functions`

Comment: This answer is old, multer's API has changed. Read the documentation.